# Is there a name for the pair (c, R), where c is the stoichiometric coefficient of a reactant R in some chemical reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I am programming a simulation, and I need a good name for a data structure that stores pairs $(c, R)$, where $c$ is the stoichiometric coefficient of a reactant $R$ in some chemical reaction. Is there a name for these pairs $(c, R)$ in chemistry?

Answer (score 1):

In chemistry, often quantities get denoted by an index $i$, which then stands for some compound ($i=\text{A, B, C, ...}$).

Examples:

- The stoichiometric coefficient $\nu_i$
- The concentration $c_i$
- The amount of substance $n_i$

The notion of grouping together the stoichiometric coefficient with the substance it uses is a novel one for me, and will most likely not have a name.

I suggest you use a name such as "coefpair" or the like and document your code accordingly.